# Creating svn branch issue

Tags: svn, branch

I have problem with SVN.

I have one repository to commit changes, the SVN info of repository:

```
[samick]$ svn info file:///home/gumm/panel_repository/
Path: panel_repository
URL: file:///home/gumm/panel_repository
Repository Root: file:///home/gumm/panel_repository
Repository UUID: 4d87f859-4380-0410-8875-df9bb2b63277
Revision: 1200
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: gumm
Last Changed Rev: 1200
Last Changed Date: 2011-01-19 23:40:43 -0800 (Wed, 19 Jan 2011)
```

When i try make branch of reposiory i get:

```
svn cp file:///home/gumm/panel_repository/ file:///home/gumm/branch/

svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/gumm'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`file:///home/gumm/panel_repository` is your repository root, you can only copy within the repository, not copy the repository somewhere else (that's what you're trying to do here).

Normally you'd have a structure in `file:///home/gumm/panel_repository` like:

```
branches
tags
trunk
```

And you copy (for example) `trunk` to `branches/myNewBranch`

Comment: Ok i understand, so can i for example.